# unifi 4.6 не отвечает на http-запросы

Tags: java, linux, http, debian

Столкнулся с проблемой установки unifi 4.6

Все действия по установке совершались на чистом дебиане (только что созданном)

```
~# lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)
~# apt-cache show unifi
Package: unifi
Version: 4.6.6-5426
~# java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-1~deb8u1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
~# mongo -version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14
```

Были добавлены ключи и соответствующие репозитории:

```
~# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv C0A52C50 
~# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
~# echo 'deb http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable ubiquiti' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/100-ubnt.list
~# echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
~# apt-get update
~# apt-get install unifi
```

Проверяю статусы служб unifi и mongo - оба запущены и активны. 
Проверяю отрытые порты:

```
~# netstat -ntlpu
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27117         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4589/mongod       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2763/mongod     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2763/mongod       
tcp6       0      0 :::8880                 :::*                    LISTEN      4553/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      4553/java              
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      4553/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8843                 :::*                    LISTEN      4553/java       
udp6       0      0 :::10001                :::*                                4553/java       
udp6       0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:56929     :::*                                4553/java        
udp6       0      0 :::3478                 :::*                                4553/java
```

В логе юнифи

```
INFO system - unknown exception
com.ubnt.data.X$_o: 
null
^
at com.ubnt.data.X$_Oo.Ò00000(Unknown Source)
at com.ubnt.data.X$_Oo.Ö00000(Unknown Source)
at com.ubnt.data.X.parseJSON(Unknown Source)
at com.ubnt.service.ooOO.C.o00000(Unknown Source)
at com.ubnt.service.ooOO.C.Õ00000(Unknown Source)
at com.ubnt.service.ooOO.C.ÒÓ0000(Unknown Source)
at com.ubnt.service.ooOO.H$5.run(Unknown Source)
at com.ubnt.ace.E$_Oo.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

При этом в браузере http://ip:8443 не открывается, а постоянно подгружается (как при ожидании ответа от сервера)
При этом:

```
~# telnet -4 localhost 8443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Проверил курлом (curl localhost:8443) и запустил strace - вот вывод

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {4605, 231368060}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {4605, 231529800}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fd234e5d8d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fd234e5d8d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
```

курл при этом просто висит...что не так с этим юнифи? Или проблема с java?
Есть подозрение что не хватает памяти (установка производиться на DigitalOcean droplet - 512Mb ). Добавил swap-раздел и настройки swappiness (10%) - ситуация не изменилась... уже не знаю, куда копать.

Answer (score 1):

судя по выводу программы *netstat*, программа *java* у вас слушает только ipv6-адреса.

а вы отправляете http-запрос на ipv4-адрес.

вероятно, надо перенастроить ваш http-сервер на прослушивание и адресов ipv4.